# MySQL Locate and Reverse query

Tags: mysql

This should be simple, but I'm getting lost in the detail....

In a database field, if the string contains a the word 'century', I would like the previous word, e.g. '16th'

I've been trying using the LOCATE and REVERSE functions, but cant make it work. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

Use substring_index to return the string before 'century'.
Use reverse to reverse the string.
Use substring_index to return the string before the first space (might need to trim it?).
Use reverse to reverse the string again.

Comment: Thank you! For reference, the SQL I ended up with is: concat(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(lcase(FREETEXT_DETAIL_EN), 'century', 1))), ' ', 1)), ' ', 'century')

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select substring_index('what century now', 'century', 1);
+---------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('what century now', 'century', 1) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| what                                              | 
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring_index('what centuries now', 'century', 1);
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('what centuries now', 'century', 1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| what centuries now                                  | 
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring_index('what century now century', 'century', 1);
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('what century now century', 'century', 1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| what                                                      | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, but select substring_index('this is from the 16th centuries now', 'century', 1); returns 'this is from the 16th centuries now', which is not what I'm after.

Comment: `centuries <> century`, if you wanna to allow plural search, is another story